# How to concatenate character strings based on condition in r?

Tags: r, string, concatenation

I need to prepare queries that are made of characters strings (DOI, Digital Object Identifier) stored in a data frame. All strings associated with the same case have to be joined to produce one query.

The df looks like this:

| Case | DOI |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1212313/dfsjk23 |
| 1 | 322332/jdkdsa12 |
| 2 | 21323/xsw.w3 |
| 2 | 311331313/q1231 |
| 2 | 1212121/1231312 |

The output should be a data frame looking like this:

| Case | Query |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | DO=(1212313/dfsjk23 OR 322332/jdkdsa12) |
| 2 | DO=(21323/xsw.w3 OR 311331313/q1231 OR 1212121/1231312) |

The prefix ("DO="), suffix (")") and "OR" are not critical, I can add them later, but how to aggregate character strings based on a case number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R you could do:

```
aggregate(DOI~Case, df1, function(x) sprintf('DO=(%s)', paste0(x, collapse = ' OR ')))
  Case                                                     DOI
1    1                 DO=(1212313/dfsjk23 OR 322332/jdkdsa12)
2    2 DO=(21323/xsw.w3 OR 311331313/q1231 OR 1212121/1231312)
```

if Using R 4.1.0

```
aggregate(DOI~Case, df1, \(x)sprintf('DO=(%s)', paste0(x, collapse = ' OR ')))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `glue` with `str_c` to `collapse` the 'DOI' column after grouping by 'Case'

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Case) %>%
   summarise(Query = glue::glue("DO=({str_c(DOI, collapse= ' OR ')})"))
```

-output

```
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#   Case Query                                                  
#  <int> <glue>                                                 
#1     1 DO=(1212313/dfsjk23 OR 322332/jdkdsa12)                
#2     2 DO=(21323/xsw.w3 OR 311331313/q1231 OR 1212121/1231312)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Case = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), DOI = c("1212313/dfsjk23", 
"322332/jdkdsa12", "21323/xsw.w3", "311331313/q1231", "1212121/1231312"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: New to this site, thank you for pointing this out.